# error in controller.php laravel (array_key_exists())

Tags: laravel

when I want to save changes in laravel, see this error :

```
/**
    * Store a newly created resource in storage.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
    * @return array|\Illuminate\Http\Response
    */

public function arrangeRoleItem($content, $module_name)
{
    if (array_key_exists(1, $content ))  { //Module Show
        $module_show = 1;
    } else {
        $module_show = 0;
    }
    if (array_key_exists(2, $content))  { // Show
        $show = 1;
    } else {
        $show = 0;
    }

    if (array_key_exists(3, $content)) { // Create
        $create = 1;
    } else {
        $create = 0;
    }
    if (array_key_exists(4, $content)) { // Edit
        $edit = 1;
    } else {
        $edit = 0;
    }
}
```

error:

```
Arguments
"array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given"
```

thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$content` variable is `null` value but `array_key_exists` function expects second parameter is array

You need to set default value like this:

```
/**
 * Arrange role item
 *
 * @param  array $content
 * @param  string $module_name
 * @return boolean $bool
 */
public function arrangeRoleItem($content = [], $module_name)
```